# C# How can I do that the int will subtract in loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, int

I've got a problem when I wanted to code a script in unity engine and I wanted to every 1 second int will subtract 1. I wrote this:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
int B - 1
```

And tmultiply this 100 times then the engine crashed help

Comment: You actually pasted/repeated that line 100 times?

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are saying here, please post more of what you are trying to do and explain what you are hoping to do (and why you are trying to do what you are doing)

Comment: (1)  What are you trying to do?  (2)  Break this into separate lines.  (3)  "int B - 1" declares an int variable named B (with no initialization, will default to value 0) then subtracts 1, but does not assign the result anywhere.  (4)  Missing ';' at the end.

Comment: I don't know anything about Unity engine, but you may want a Timer object with an increment set to 1000 ms (1 second) and an event handler that decrements B.

Comment: @Technophile - I'm nitpicking for nitpicking's sake on point #3, but `int B - 1` is just nonsensical. It is not legal C# code. Further, local variables (as this appears to be) do not have a default value and must be explicitly initialized.

Answer (score 3):

This is what can be understood from your question:

```
int b = 12411; // whatever you want it to be

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    b--;
}
```

However, this is likely to kill Unity as this will take 100 seconds to complete. What you need is a background operation scheduled to run every second, like a Timer does. In Unity, however, this is best achieved by coroutines, like this one (taken from [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/c-timer-event.127920/)):

```
class YourClassName
{
    int b;
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("MyEvent");
        b = 100; //some number
    }

    private IEnumerator MyEvent()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); // wait a second
            b--;
        }
    }
}
```